# Связанные списки/linked lists

Tags: c++, c, списки, односвязный-список

Изучаю сейчас самостоятельно связанные списки С. Кто-нибудь может сказать, почему, несмотря на то, что в последнем цикле while я вывожу лишь l1, l2 каким-то образом тоже выводится?

```
  #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
//dummy=head
struct node {
    int value;
    struct node *next;
    };

struct node *head;
struct node *tail;

struct node *init(void) {
    head=(struct node *) malloc(sizeof *head);
    tail=(struct node *) malloc(sizeof *head);
    head->next = tail; tail->next = tail;
    return head;
}

struct node *append(int v) {
    struct node *ptr;
    struct node *t;
    ptr=head;
    while (ptr->next != tail) ptr = ptr->next;
    t=(struct node *) malloc(sizeof *t);

    t->value=v;
    t->next = tail;
    ptr->next = t;
    return ptr;
}

struct node *insert(int v, struct node *ptr) {
    struct node *t;
    t=(struct node *) malloc(sizeof *t);
    ptr->value=v;
    t->value=v;
    t->next = tail;
    ptr->next = t;
    return ptr;
    }

void delete(struct node *ptr) {
    struct node *t;
    t = ptr->next;
    ptr->next = ptr->next->next;
    free(t);
    }

int main () {
struct node *l1, *l2;

int n, v;
scanf("%d", &n);
l1=init();
l2=init();
int i=0;
while(i<n){
        scanf("%d", &v);
l1=append(v);
i++;}

l1=l1->next;
scanf("%d", &v);
l1=insert(v, l1);
delete(l1);
i=0;
while(i<n){
        scanf("%d", &v);
l2=append(v);
i++;
}

l2=l2->next;
scanf("%d", &v);
l2=insert(v, l2);
delete(l2);

l1=head->next;
while (l1 != tail) {
    printf("%d\n",l1->value);
    l1 = l1->next;
    }

return 0;
}
```

Comment: @dropitlikeitshot, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Потому что после второго вызова `init()` переменные `head` и `tail` отражают список `l2` (даже когда Вы вызываете `append(l1)` и т.п.).

---

Кстати, после `delete` у Вас идет обращение к данным в уже освобожденной памяти. Это неправильно и поведение (упадет или нет программа) зависит от версии аллокатора памяти.

---

Идея же использовать фиктивные элементы в начале и конце списка IMHO довольно странная, так же как и последний элемент списка (фиктивный), зацикливающий указатель на себя.

**Обновление**

[[@dropitlikeitshot](/users/25099/dropitlikeitshot)](/users/25099/dropitlikeitshot), при чем тут какие-то dummy node?

Насколько я вижу код, Вы пытаетесь делать 2 списка (в main) l1 и l2, **но для обеих** оперируете в своих функциях **одними и теми же глобальными head и tail**.

Вот тут то  у Вас все и перемешивается. Выбросьте их.

Сделайте структуру, содержащую для каждого списка *его* head и tail. И вот указатель на такую структуру (у Вас это будут 2 списка l1 и l2) и передавайте в функции, которые манипулируют списками.

---

Сейчас Вы просто сами хотите изобрести общие алгоритмы для работы со списками? Увлекательное занятие.

Comment: @avp то есть фактически я могу писать в данном коде просто append(v), а не l2=append(v), ибо функция append итак оперирует с head, который отражает l2?

---

А какую альтернативу dummy nod'ам вы предлагаете?

Comment: Обновил ответ

Comment: @avp thanx)

Для тренировки в программировании иногда полезно изобрести велосипед..

Comment: @dropitlikeitshot, да я тоже люблю такой велоспорт.

Только к своим велосипедам желательно еще прилагать инструкцию на русском языке  
(комментарии перед функциями init, append, insert ... *что именно Вы намеряны сделать*).

--

Кстати, ну и как показал себя велосипед с признаком конца списка в виде указателя на себя вместо NULL? Удобнее обычного?  
(я в общем-то не иронизирую, а просто интересуюсь).

Comment: @avp ну, я пробую..